# How to print results in dataframe format after using a for loop

Tags: python, pandas, for-loop, iteration

I am analyzing some data. I got my for loop to print in array format but i wanted to print the results back in a data frame format as i am working with data frames.

```
import itertools 

for time, flight in itertools.izip(flight_data["AirTime"], flight_data["UniqueCarrier"]):
    if time > 300:
        print (time, flight)
Outputs:(340, AA)
```

However, I want the output to return back in a dataframe format. Please assist thanks

Answer (score 2):

Use [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#boolean-indexing):

```
print (flight_data[flight_data.AirTime > 300])
```

Sample:

```
flight_data = pd.DataFrame({'AirTime':[340,200,110],
                            'UniqueCarrier':['AA','SS','DD']})

print (flight_data)
   AirTime UniqueCarrier
0      340            AA
1      200            SS
2      110            DD


print (flight_data[flight_data.AirTime > 300])
   AirTime UniqueCarrier
0      340            AA
```